# How do I get the y axis display of a matplotlib OHLC candlestick chart to show the OHLC values rather than the y axis cursor position

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I am using matplotlib to create an OHLC candlestick stock price chart. I am using mpl_finance's candlestick_ohlc module to create the chart. Creating the chart is straightforward, however the `x` and `y` axis display at the bottom of the chart shows the date and y axis value for a given cursor position but I would like the `x` and `y` axis display to show the date and that dates open, high, low, close (ohlc) values rather than just a date and a `y` axis cursor position value. The quotes dataset is in the format of a list of tuples where each tuple contains the date as a number followed by the open, high, low, close and volume.

I am trying to use matplotlib's format_coord function to specify the ohlc values but I can not figure out how to get the format_coord function to accept the list containing the dates and associated ohlc values as an input and to then give the desired date and OHLC output. The following is some simplified code I have written that exhibits my issue:
The code below has now been modified so that it fully works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator, DayLocator, MONDAY
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, num2date


def ohlc_daily_date_axis():
    mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)  
    alldays = DayLocator()            
    weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d %Y')  # e.g., Jan 12 2018

    quotes = [(737042.0, 2.72, 2.78, 2.6815, 2.74, 414378.0),
              (737045.0, 2.71, 2.77, 2.57, 2.63, 578841.0),
              (737046.0, 2.64, 2.64, 2.4228, 2.47, 1451450.0),
              (737047.0, 2.9, 3.15, 2.7, 2.96, 7230260.0),
              (737048.0, 2.92, 3.29, 2.67, 2.83, 2784110.0),
              (737049.0, 2.78, 2.82, 2.4701, 2.51, 822776.0),
              (737052.0, 2.56, 2.6344, 2.49, 2.5, 278883.0),
              (737054.0, 2.5, 2.619, 2.34, 2.6, 606002.0),
              (737055.0, 2.57, 2.63, 2.45, 2.57, 1295820.0),
              (737056.0, 2.57, 2.75, 2.51, 2.65, 435838.0)]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5))
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)

    candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.6)

    ax.xaxis_date()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, 
horizontalalignment='right')
    #the following line puts the ohlc data in the y axis display
    ax.format_coord = get_ohlc_from_date_xy
    # the following line puts the ohlc data in the x axis display
    #ax.fmt_xdata = get_ohlc_from_date_x

    plt.show()

def get_ohlc_from_date_x(dateasnum):
    print('dateasnum: ', int(dateasnum))
    quotes = [(737042.0, 2.72, 2.78, 2.6815, 2.74, 414378.0),
              (737045.0, 2.71, 2.77, 2.57, 2.63, 578841.0),
              (737046.0, 2.64, 2.64, 2.4228, 2.47, 1451450.0),
              (737047.0, 2.9, 3.15, 2.7, 2.96, 7230260.0),
              (737048.0, 2.92, 3.29, 2.67, 2.83, 2784110.0),
              (737049.0, 2.78, 2.82, 2.4701, 2.51, 822776.0),
              (737052.0, 2.56, 2.6344, 2.49, 2.5, 278883.0),
              (737054.0, 2.5, 2.619, 2.34, 2.6, 606002.0),
              (737055.0, 2.57, 2.63, 2.45, 2.57, 1295820.0),
              (737056.0, 2.57, 2.75, 2.51, 2.65, 435838.0)]
    for i in range(len(quotes)):
        if int(dateasnum) == quotes[i][0]:
            open = quotes[i][1]
            high = quotes[i][2]
            low = quotes[i][3]
            close = quotes[i][4]
            vol = quotes[i][5]
    dte = str(num2date(dateasnum).date())
    print('type(dte): ', type(dte))
    print('open: ', open)
    ohlc_str = dte + ' open: ' + str(open) + ' high: ' + str(high) + ' 
low: ' + str(low) + ' close: ' + str(close) + ' vol: ' + str(int(vol)) 
+ '    '

    return ohlc_str



def get_ohlc_from_date_xy(dateasnum,y):
    print('dateasnum: ', int(dateasnum))
    quotes = [(737042.0, 2.72, 2.78, 2.6815, 2.74, 414378.0),
              (737045.0, 2.71, 2.77, 2.57, 2.63, 578841.0),
              (737046.0, 2.64, 2.64, 2.4228, 2.47, 1451450.0),
              (737047.0, 2.9, 3.15, 2.7, 2.96, 7230260.0),
              (737048.0, 2.92, 3.29, 2.67, 2.83, 2784110.0),
              (737049.0, 2.78, 2.82, 2.4701, 2.51, 822776.0),
              (737052.0, 2.56, 2.6344, 2.49, 2.5, 278883.0),
              (737054.0, 2.5, 2.619, 2.34, 2.6, 606002.0),
              (737055.0, 2.57, 2.63, 2.45, 2.57, 1295820.0),
              (737056.0, 2.57, 2.75, 2.51, 2.65, 435838.0)]
    for i in range(len(quotes)):
        if int(dateasnum) == quotes[i][0]:
            open = quotes[i][1]
            high = quotes[i][2]
            low = quotes[i][3]
            close = quotes[i][4]
            vol = quotes[i][5]
    dte = str(num2date(dateasnum).date())
    #print('type(dte): ', type(dte))
    #print('open: ', open)
    ohlc_str = 'open: ' + str(open) + ' high: ' + str(high) + ' 
low: ' + str(low) + ' close: ' + str(close) + ' vol: ' + str(int(vol))

    return dte, ohlc_str



# This def does not work
def format_coord(x,y, quotes):
    for i in range(len(quotes)):
        if int(x) == quotes[i]:
            open = quotes[i][1]
            high = quotes[i][2]
            low = quotes[i][3]
            close = quotes[i][4]
            vol = quotes[i][5]
    y = 'open: ' + open # I'm just using open to simplify things
    x = DateFormatter('%b %d %Y')
    return (x,y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ohlc_daily_date_axis()
```

If I run this code as it is I get the following error (This is the error I got when I was using the incorrect `def format_coord(x,y, quotes)` approach):

```
File "/Users/Me/Mee/python_db_programs/learn_matplotlib_test.py", line 33, 
in ohlc_daily_date_axis
    ax.format_coord = format_coord(quotes)
TypeError: format_coord() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' 
and 'quotes'
```

If I comment out the `ax.format_coord = format_coord(quotes)` line then the code runs fine but without my desired date and ohlc values in the `x` and `y` display. Any help on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

I ended up not trying to change the `y` display but instead added the ohlc values to the `x` display. Which means I changed `ax.format_coord = format_coord(quotes)` to the command that just formats the `x` coordinate, which is `ax.fmt_xdata` and then wrote a `def` that used the quotes list to get each dates corresponding ohlc data:

```
ax.fmt_xdata = get_ohlc_from_date
```

instead of

```
ax.format_coord = format_coord(quotes)
```

and then added this def:

```
def get_ohlc_from_date(dateasnum):
    print('dateasnum: ', int(dateasnum))
    quotes = [(737042.0, 2.72, 2.78, 2.6815, 2.74, 414378.0),
              (737045.0, 2.71, 2.77, 2.57, 2.63, 578841.0),
              (737046.0, 2.64, 2.64, 2.4228, 2.47, 1451450.0),
              (737047.0, 2.9, 3.15, 2.7, 2.96, 7230260.0),
              (737048.0, 2.92, 3.29, 2.67, 2.83, 2784110.0),
              (737049.0, 2.78, 2.82, 2.4701, 2.51, 822776.0),
              (737052.0, 2.56, 2.6344, 2.49, 2.5, 278883.0),
              (737054.0, 2.5, 2.619, 2.34, 2.6, 606002.0),
              (737055.0, 2.57, 2.63, 2.45, 2.57, 1295820.0),
              (737056.0, 2.57, 2.75, 2.51, 2.65, 435838.0)]
    for i in range(len(quotes)):
        if int(dateasnum) == quotes[i][0]:
            open = quotes[i][1]
            high = quotes[i][2]
            low = quotes[i][3]
            close = quotes[i][4]
            vol = quotes[i][5]
    dte = str(num2date(dateasnum).date())
    print('type(dte): ', type(dte))
    print('open: ', open)
    ohlc_str = dte + ' open: ' + str(open) + ' high: ' + str(high) + ' 
low: ' + str(low) + ' close: ' + str(close) + ' vol: ' + str(int(vol)) 
+ '    '

    return ohlc_str
```

Also because I used matplotlibs dateasnum function I had to import that as well:

```
from matplotlib.dates import num2date
```

While this does not replace the `y` axis coordinate with the ohlc values it does provide the ohlc values in the `x` and `y` axis display

After figuring out how to add the ohlc values to the `x` axis display I realized that the logic I used to add the ohlc values to the `x` axis display could be applied to the `y` axis display allowing for the display of the ohlc values in the `y` axis parameter. This was accomplished by using the `ax.format_coord = format_coord` command and creating a new def that assigned the ohlc values to the `y` axis return value. I have modified the original code I posted so that depending on whether or not the `ax.format_coord = format_coord` line or the `ax.fmt_xdata = get_ohlc_from_date` line is commented out determines if the ohlc values are displayed as part of the `x` axis display or as part of the `y` axis display

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Hi, I was trying to figure out how to get the y axis display to show the OHLC values rather than the y axis cursor position. I was able to solve the problem and subsequently modified the code to show the solution.

Comment: Ok, so you have misunderstood the concept of a Q&A. You ask a question and you or anyone else can provide an answer. So please put everything that answers your question in an **answer**.

Comment: Hi, It was unclear to me how I should have provided an answer to a question I asked. In this case I changed my original question so that it provided my answer. I see that what I should have done was clicked the Answer Your Question button at the bottom of the page and then posted the correct code there. In retrospect that seems obvious. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: What do you mean "in retrospect"? Just do it now?!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution which allows for the x and y axis readout of a matplotlib OHLC candlestick chart to display the OHLC values in the Y axis readout rather than the Y axis cursor position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator, DayLocator, 
MONDAY
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, num2date


def ohlc_daily_date_axis():
    mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)  
    alldays = DayLocator()            
    weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d %Y')  # e.g., Jan 12 2018

    quotes = [(737042.0, 2.72, 2.78, 2.6815, 2.74, 414378.0),
              (737045.0, 2.71, 2.77, 2.57, 2.63, 578841.0),
              (737046.0, 2.64, 2.64, 2.4228, 2.47, 1451450.0),
              (737047.0, 2.9, 3.15, 2.7, 2.96, 7230260.0),
              (737048.0, 2.92, 3.29, 2.67, 2.83, 2784110.0),
              (737049.0, 2.78, 2.82, 2.4701, 2.51, 822776.0),
              (737052.0, 2.56, 2.6344, 2.49, 2.5, 278883.0),
              (737054.0, 2.5, 2.619, 2.34, 2.6, 606002.0),
              (737055.0, 2.57, 2.63, 2.45, 2.57, 1295820.0),
              (737056.0, 2.57, 2.75, 2.51, 2.65, 435838.0)]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5))
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)

    candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.6)

    ax.xaxis_date()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, 
horizontalalignment='right')
    #the following line puts the ohlc data in the y axis display
    ax.format_coord = get_ohlc_from_date_xy
    # the following line puts the ohlc data in the x axis display
    #ax.fmt_xdata = get_ohlc_from_date_x

    plt.show()

def get_ohlc_from_date_x(dateasnum):
    print('dateasnum: ', int(dateasnum))
    quotes = [(737042.0, 2.72, 2.78, 2.6815, 2.74, 414378.0),
              (737045.0, 2.71, 2.77, 2.57, 2.63, 578841.0),
              (737046.0, 2.64, 2.64, 2.4228, 2.47, 1451450.0),
              (737047.0, 2.9, 3.15, 2.7, 2.96, 7230260.0),
              (737048.0, 2.92, 3.29, 2.67, 2.83, 2784110.0),
              (737049.0, 2.78, 2.82, 2.4701, 2.51, 822776.0),
              (737052.0, 2.56, 2.6344, 2.49, 2.5, 278883.0),
              (737054.0, 2.5, 2.619, 2.34, 2.6, 606002.0),
              (737055.0, 2.57, 2.63, 2.45, 2.57, 1295820.0),
              (737056.0, 2.57, 2.75, 2.51, 2.65, 435838.0)]
    for i in range(len(quotes)):
        if int(dateasnum) == quotes[i][0]:
            open = quotes[i][1]
            high = quotes[i][2]
            low = quotes[i][3]
            close = quotes[i][4]
            vol = quotes[i][5]
    dte = str(num2date(dateasnum).date())
    print('type(dte): ', type(dte))
    print('open: ', open)
    ohlc_str = dte + ' open: ' + str(open) + ' high: ' + str(high) + ' 
low: ' + str(low) + ' close: ' + str(close) + ' vol: ' + str(int(vol)) 
+ '    '

    return ohlc_str



def get_ohlc_from_date_xy(dateasnum,y):
    print('dateasnum: ', int(dateasnum))
    quotes = [(737042.0, 2.72, 2.78, 2.6815, 2.74, 414378.0),
              (737045.0, 2.71, 2.77, 2.57, 2.63, 578841.0),
              (737046.0, 2.64, 2.64, 2.4228, 2.47, 1451450.0),
              (737047.0, 2.9, 3.15, 2.7, 2.96, 7230260.0),
              (737048.0, 2.92, 3.29, 2.67, 2.83, 2784110.0),
              (737049.0, 2.78, 2.82, 2.4701, 2.51, 822776.0),
              (737052.0, 2.56, 2.6344, 2.49, 2.5, 278883.0),
              (737054.0, 2.5, 2.619, 2.34, 2.6, 606002.0),
              (737055.0, 2.57, 2.63, 2.45, 2.57, 1295820.0),
              (737056.0, 2.57, 2.75, 2.51, 2.65, 435838.0)]
    for i in range(len(quotes)):
        if int(dateasnum) == quotes[i][0]:
            open = quotes[i][1]
            high = quotes[i][2]
            low = quotes[i][3]
            close = quotes[i][4]
            vol = quotes[i][5]
    dte = str(num2date(dateasnum).date())
    #print('type(dte): ', type(dte))
    #print('open: ', open)
    ohlc_str = 'open: ' + str(open) + ' high: ' + str(high) + ' 
low: ' + str(low) + ' close: ' + str(close) + ' vol: ' + str(int(vol))

    return dte, ohlc_str






if __name__ == '__main__':
    ohlc_daily_date_axis()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Plotly's CandleStick Chart](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/), with have all that you want built-in.

[Here is a example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkZT1.png)

**Sequence of tuple to Dataframe**

To do this you need your data to be inside a dataframe with columns `["Date", "High", "Low", "Open", "Close"]`, take a look at [pandas.DataFrame.from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to import your data to a DataFrame as it creates a DataFrame object from a sequence of tuples.

**Other**

- You might need to convert the dates to datetime, look at [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert it

**The Answer to the question**

From the plotly's [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_candlestick):

> hoverinfo – Determines which trace information appear on hover. If none or skip are set, no information is displayed upon hovering. But, if none is set, click and hover events are still fired.

Also it is worth to read:
[Hover Text and Formatting in Python](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/)

**Final consideration**

I know it is not made with matplotlib as you wanted, but I think it is relevant as an answer.

**Code**

```py
def generatePlotly(df):
    layout = go.Layout(
        plot_bgcolor="#FFF",      # Sets background color to white
        hovermode="x",
        hoverdistance=100,        # Distance to show hover label of data point
        spikedistance=1000,       # Distance to show spike
        xaxis=dict(
            title="Data",         # X Axis Title
            linecolor="#BCCCDC",  # Sets color of X-axis line
            showgrid=False,       # Removes X-axis grid lines
            showspikes=True,      # Show spike line for X-axis
            gridcolor="#BCCCDC",  # Grid color, if enabled
            # Format spike - Show a Line at the pointer
            spikethickness=2,
            spikedash="dot",
            spikecolor="#999999",
            spikemode="across",
            fixedrange=True,
            spikesnap="cursor",
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            title="Preço (R$)",   # Y Axis Title
            linecolor="#BCCCDC",  # Sets color of Y-axis line
            showgrid=False,       # Removes Y-axis grid lines
            gridcolor="#BCCCDC",  # Grid color, if enabled
            showspikes=True,      # Show spike line for X-axis
            # Format spike - Show a Line at the pointer
            spikethickness=2,
            spikedash="dot",
            spikecolor="#999999",
            spikemode="across",
            fixedrange=True,
            side="right",
            spikesnap="cursor",
        ),
        margin=go.layout.Margin(
            l=0,  # left margin
            r=0,  # right margin
            b=0,  # bottom margin
            t=0,  # top margin
        ),
    )

    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Candlestick(
                x=df["Date"],      # Your data
                open=df["Open"],   
                high=df["High"],
                low=df["Low"],
                close=df["Close"],
            )
        ],
        layout=layout,
    )
    # Remove rangeslider from the chart, you can just comment the next line
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)

    # Legend position
    fig.update_layout(legend=dict(yanchor="top", y=0.99, xanchor="left", x=0.01)) 

    ############################################################
    # For this part look at EXTRAS at the bottom of the answer #
    ############################################################
    # build complete timepline from start date to end date
    dt_all = pd.date_range(start=df["Date"].iloc[0], end=df["Date"].iloc[-1])
    # retrieve the dates that ARE in the original datset
    dt_obs = [d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for d in pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])]
    # define dates with missing values
    dt_breaks = [d for d in dt_all.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist() if not d in dt_obs]
    fig.update_xaxes(
        rangebreaks=[
            # dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),  # hide weekends
            dict(values=dt_breaks)
        ]
    )

    # Hover Distance and Hover Info
    # fig.update_layout(hoverdistance=0)
    # fig.update_traces(xaxis="x", hoverinfo="none")

    fig.show()
```

**Extras**

[Plotly: How to style a plotly figure so that it doesn't display gaps for missing dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62531751/15494443)