# How to display complete range of dates referencing df containing NULL values?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

For a R-Shiny application and using the plotly package I would like to graph a set of numeric values corresponding to hourly timestamps. I've prepared the dataframe the plotly package references to include NULL values where an actual value does not exist for a particular hourly timestamp. I've attached an example of what this dataframe might look like:

*filtered_data*

| ts | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2009-07-01 00:02:00 | 18.7 |
| 2009-07-01 00:03:00 | 18.4 |
| 2009-07-01 00:04:00 | NULL |
| 2009-07-01 00:05:00 | NULL |
| 2009-07-01 00:06:00 | NULL |
| 2009-07-01 00:07:00 | 18.9 |

When I plot this data, these NULL values are not being plotted. In the example above, the plot would jump from a timestamp of 2009-07-01 00:03:00 to 2009-07-01 00:07:00 and in the R-Studio console window a "Warning: Ignoring 3 observations" would appear. Instead, I would like this time gap to be displayed as an empty space like [in this example](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#hiding-weekends-and-holidays):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO1LX.png)

At first I was using a dataframe without a complete set of dates:

| ts | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2009-07-01 00:02:00 | 18.7 |
| 2009-07-01 00:03:00 | 18.4 |
| 2009-07-01 00:07:00 | 18.9 |

I've tried to replace NA values in the dataframe before plotting using another palatable numeric value but this solution feels a little "hacky", at least in the way I've tried to implement that solution so far as these replacement values are still plotted and need to be obscured in some way. Is this solution avoidable? I believe the ignored observations are coming from y = ~value, where ~value is currently null.

I've seen a few Stack [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346100/plotly-how-to-style-a-plotly-figure-so-that-it-doesnt-display-gaps-for-missing) with users encountering what seems to be the opposite problem. Thank you.

Code snippet in use:

```
plotDataTable$data <- filtered_data
for (i in 1:length(plotSelectedVariables())) {
        var <- plotSelectedVariables()[i]
        marker_symbol <- marker_symbols2[(i - 1) %% length(marker_symbols2) + 1L]
        subset_data <- filtered_data
        subset_data$ts <- as.POSIXct(subset_data$ts,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        subset_data$ts <- format(subset_data$ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        subset_data$grade_flag2[is.na(subset_data$grade_flag2)] <- 'NA'
        hover_text <- with(subset_data, paste0("Variable: ", var, "<br>Value:", value, "<br>Grade 1 Flag: ", grade_flag, "<br>Grade 2 Flag: ", grade_flag2, "<br>Time:", ts))
        discrete_color <- c("green", "skyblue", "black", "violet", "orange")
        discrete_color <- setNames(discrete_color, c("A", "M", "NA", "R", "S"))
        p <- add_trace(p,
                       data = subset_data,
                       x = ~ts,
                       y = ~value,
                       name = paste0(var, " Grade 2: ", subset_data$grade_flag2),
                       text = hover_text,
                       type = "scatter",
                       mode = "markers",
                       color = subset_data$grade_flag2,
                       colors = discrete_color
        )
      }
      print("finished for loop")
    
    p <- p %>% plotly::layout(
      xaxis = list(
        title = "Time",
        type = "category",  # Set the x-axis type to 'category' for discrete values
        tickformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",  # Set the x-axis tick format
        tickangle = 45  # Set the x-axis tick angle to 45 degrees
      ),
      yaxis = list(title = "Variable"),
      dragmode = "select",
      showlegend = TRUE,
      legend = list(
        orientation = "v",
        xanchor = "right",
        yanchor = "top",
        x = 1,
        y = 1,
        title = list("Observation Plot"),
        height = 1800
      )
    )
    print("finished layout")
    
    # Update the reactive value with the new plot
    plot_data2(p)
    print('returning from updatePlot2')
    # Render the plot
    output$obs_plot2 <- renderPlotly({
      plot_data2()
    })
```

**EDIT**
[Portion of SQL dataframe filtered_data is referencing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4QkR.png)

dput()

```
structure(list(ts = structure(c(1246406400, 1246410000, 1246413600, 
1246417200, 1246420800, 1246424400, 1246428000, 1246431600, 1246435200, 
1246438800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    station_id = c(NA, "CHMO", "CHMO", "CHMO", "CHMO", "CHMO", 
    "CHMO", "CHMO", "CHMO", "CHMO"), variable = c(NA, "ATAV", 
    "ATAV", "ATAV", "ATAV", "ATAV", "ATAV", "ATAV", "ATAV", "ATAV"
    ), value = c(NA, 0, 9.3, 8.6, 7.9, 7.3, 6.9, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9
    ), grade_flag = c(NA, "S", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A"), grade_flag2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using `NA` (which has length 1) instead of `NULL` (which has length 0) in your data frame. If you share some sample data in a copy/pasteable format that will help us help you. Since vectors can't contain `NULL` elements, I'm not sure whether your `value` column is `list` class or `character` class, or something else. Maybe post `dput(filtered_data[1:10, ])` to share code that will recreate the first 10 rows of `filtered_data`, including all data structure and class info.

Comment: Sure, thank you for your suggestions. I've posted dput(filtered_data[1:10, ]). It's interesting that the null values 'grade_flag2' are posting with <NA> while 'value' does not show it's <NA> values. For example, the first row of the dput(filtered_data[1:10, ]) should actually have an <NA> value for this particular query.

Comment: The point of `dput` is that it's copy/pasteable so we can paste in into our R sessions and recreate your data. Since we can't paste an image into R, could you please post the `dput()` as text?

Comment: Sure, I've just posted the dput() as text. Please note the first value in column 'value' is NA, this (and other NA values like it) are what I'd like to be able to include on the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, these points **are** shown as gaps:

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(20220307)
dd <- tibble(tm = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2024-01-01 00:00:00"),
                      to = as.POSIXct("2024-02-01 00:00:00"),
                      by = "3 hours")) %>% 
  mutate(y = rpois(n(), 200),
         id = 1:n())

plot_ly(dd) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~ tm, y = ~ y, mode = "markers", type = "scatter")


dd_mis <- dd %>% 
  mutate(y = if_else(between(id, 20, 60), NA_real_, y))
plot_ly(dd_mis) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~ tm, y = ~ y, mode = "markers", type = "scatter")
```

#### Full Plot (`dd`)

[image: Scatterplot of time vs a random variable with blue dots]

#### Missing points (`dd_mis`)

[image: Scatterplot of time vs a random variable with blue dots and a visible gap of missing values]

You clearly see that there is an area where no points are plotted.

If you decide to draw a line (`mode = "lines"`) you may want to explore `connectgaps`, which allows either to leave the space blank (`FALSE`) or to connect the endpoints (`TRUE`)